# Redirect output to log file while using `flock`

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I've got a bash script like this:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

locks="/var/lock/userlocks"
lock=`basename "$0"`.exclusivelock

(
flock -x -w 5 200 || { echo "exiting. $lock already in use."; exit 1; }
echo "$lock acquired."
#do stuff

) 200>$locks/$lock
```

I can send all the output to a log file like this:

```
$ test.sh >> logfile.log 2>&1
```

But could I put that output redirection into the script like this?

test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

locks="/var/lock/userlocks"
lock=`basename "$0"`.exclusivelock

(
flock -x -w 5 200 || { echo "exiting. $lock already in use."; exit 1; }
echo "$lock acquired."
#do stuff

) 200>$locks/$lock >> logfile.log 2>&1
```

Now call the script without needing to redirect.

```
$ test2.sh
```